# Magento2 browser fingerprinting

Tags: magento2.4, browser

How does Magento2 use browser fingerprinting to associate a personal browsing session with a web visitor ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a built-in browser fingerprint feature inside Magento? Did you install any module or add any js script to your pages that is calculating this browser fingerprint?
You would have to implement the functionality and decide how do you want to use this fingerprint withing your store. We are using it by passing it over to our fraud API, when the user does specific actions, along with specific information, like what product did the customer choose, if he is typing his information on the guest checkout page, we are sending his name, email, and address, etc. And based on this information that we are sending throughout the user's journey, there is a final decision which basically tells us if the user is suspected of fraud or not, so we either let them place the order or not based on this decision.
But other companies might use this browser fingerprint to identify the user across websites, not in the user's best intentions, for example to build the user's profile so that he can be later targeted by ads.

Comment: I haven't add any module and js files, if I can build a module, but don't know how to write for fingerprint js, I want to return a message to the customer after placing orders, need according to the browser fingerprint is to verify that the information I returned to determine the customer, and not return the information to other customers, I think through the browser fingerprint uniqueness to verify customer's real

Comment: Why not use the PHP Session ID in this case? You can get it from the cookie. Or, if the customer is logged in, just use his Customer ID